# Get the dropdown data and update the data in Django

Tags: python, django

Dear all of the Django developer community, I am facing this below issue:

I try to update a db table data which has one field and one drop down field. But I only get basic field data and not drop down list data.

I request expert help me. How can I fix this issue?

Advanced Thanks For All

views.py

```
def update_brands(request, id):
    brand = Brand.objects.get(id=id)
    form = AddBrandForms(request.POST, instance=brand)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/parts/brands')
    return render(request, 'parts/edit_brands.html', {'brand': brand })
```

edit_brands.html

```
{% extends 'parts/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <form method="post" action="/parts/update_brands/{{brand.id}}/" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Country Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="country" value="{{ brand.brand_name }}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Country Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <select id="cars" name="cars">
            {% for db in dbf.all %}
              <option value="{{ db.db}}">{{ db.db}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{% extends 'parts/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <form method="post" action="/parts/update_brands/{{brand.id}}/" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Country Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" name="country" value="{{ brand.brand_name }}"/>
         </div>
     </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
         <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Country Name:</label>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
          <select id="cars" name="cars">
            {% for car in brand.all %}
               <option value="{{ car }}">{{ car }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: thank you for you solution . but after i use this solution then it's show this error .. TypeError at /parts/edit_brands/1/

'Brand' object is not iterable

Comment: Sorry, silly mistake. I have corrected my initial code. The for loop was meant to say brand.all